# Hide SharePoint columns unless one of the following columns contains keyword

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I am trying to make a column in a modern SharePoint list only be visible if one of any of the following columns are equal to the word 'ladder'.

- [$Escalation1]
- [$Escalation2]
- [$Escalation3]
- [$Escalation4]

I have been attempting to do it with a conditional formula but have been unable to find a formula that works. I tried using Bard / Chatgpt but was unable to get a working formula from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula like below to show/hide fields on list form based on escalation columns:

```
=if([$Escalation1]=='ladder' || [$Escalation2]=='ladder' || [$Escalation3]=='ladder' || [$Escalation4]=='ladder','true','false')
```

Make sure you are using correct internal names of your escalation columns in above formula.

You can get the exact internal name of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Follow this Microsoft official documentation for more information and steps to add formula: [Specify conditional formula to show or hide SharePoint list columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

**Note**:

1. `if`, `true`, `false` and value `ladder` in formula are case-sensitive. So, use correct keywords in your formula.

Comment: Excellent that has worked perfectly. I think I had been thrown off by the case when previously trying it